# SSH automatizar acceso a directorios

Tags: visual-studio, vscode, ssh, server

En VSCode he instalado "Remote - SSH" Mi archivo de configuración:

```
Host Raspberry
  HostName XXX.XXX.XXX.XX
  User psdo
```

Se conecta sin problemas pero una vez conectado quiero que vaya automáticamente a una ruta que normalmente teclearía en la terminal de esta forma:

```
  cd /
  cd /media/usb
```

Cómo hago para que lo haga automáticamente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo te aconsejo que si es un usuario que tienes exclusivamente para trabajar con ese directorio añadas la instrucción

```
cd /media/usb
```

a tu archivo *$HOME/.bashrc* al final del mismo.

Saludos

Comment: Gracias! esa era la solución a mi problema.

Comment: Me alegro :). Saludos.